# p element not deleting ondrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div box: .box001, .box002.

When I drag and drop .box002 with id="1" to another div - .box001 with id="10" dragged element deletes ondrop also background-color becomes none, likewise box002 with id="2" to box001 with id="20"  and third box similary

i want to delete the p element with name1, name2, name3 on each drop.

how to achieve it?

```js
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);    // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  document.getElementsByClassName(ev.target.className).innerHTML = '';  // which box p  should blank 
}
```

```css
.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font: 70px;
  ;
  color: #001a00;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
  <p id="11"> name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
  <p id="12">name1</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
  <p id="13">name1</p>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how to achieve the p element delete on each drop?

Answer (score 0):

> try this:
>
> ```js
> function allowDrop(ev)
> {
>   ev.preventDefault();
> }
> function drag(ev)
> {
>   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
> }
> function drop(ev)
> {
>   ev.preventDefault();
>   var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
>   alert(data);
>   var el = document.getElementById("1"+data);
>
>   el.remove(el);    // deleting drag item
>
>   ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
>   document.getElementsByClassName(ev.target.className).innerHTML = '';  // which box p  should blank 
> }
> ```
>
> ```css
> .box001 {
>   float: left;
>   width: 50px;
>   height: 50px;
>   border: 1px solid black;
>   border-radius: 10%;
>   background-color: #42e0fd;
>   font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
>   font: 70px;
>   ;
>   color: #001a00;
>   font-size: xx-small;
>   font-weight: 900;
>   text-align: center;
> }
>
> .box002 {
>   float: left;
>   width: 50px;
>   height: 50px;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
>   <p id="11"> name1</p>
> </div>
> <div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
>   <p id="12">name1</p>
> </div>
> <div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
>   <p id="13">name1</p>
> </div>
>
>
> <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
>   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
> </div>
> <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
>   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
> </div>
> <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
>   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
> </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Comment: drag first img and drop into 1 element. similarly with 2nd and 3rd img